# Best way to display and content manage a forfeit on a sports site?

Tags: data-display

I designed and built a website for one of my sports leagues. I thought I had everything covered until there was a forfeit. Since I also built a CMS for the site to be managed by the league operators, they just made the score 1-0.
[image]
The challenges posed by a forfeit is that there is not a score, but it is counted as a win for the team that didn't forfeit. One idea I have is to add an asterisk to the losing score indicating a forfeit that the content editor can toggle, but as the infomercial phrase goes, "There's got to be a better way!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to score a forfeit**

Rules vary on how to score a forfeit, I would look up the rules for your specific case. E.g. for FIFA it is 3-0 (if the score from the winning team isn't higher) (see [wikipedia on forfeit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forfeit_(sport))).

**How to display a forfeit**

I would display both the score and a label with forfeit. I think forfeit should be more prominent because the score is artificial in that case. Something like the example below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think just adding the forfeit toggle and display is the way to go. The sport this is for is football so 1-0 is impossible, but I think it's good to remind the user that it was a forfeit and the score of 1-0 wasn't a typo.

Comment: The good news was that my content editor was able to figure it out and find a solution sans toggle.